# How to find sum objects inside an array using mongoose ,node ,

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

This is my collection ...

```
var emp = new Schema({
    names: String,
    details: [{
        date: String,
        wage: String,
        sack: String,
        sellername: String
    }]

});
```

possible output of the collection

```
{   name: john
    details: [{
        date:12-01-2019
        wage:210
        sack:10
        sellername: cristy   
    }]
    details: [{
        date:12-01-2019
        wage:210
        sack:10
        sellername: cristy
    }]
    details: [{
        date:12-01-2019
        wage:210
        sack:10
        sellername: cristy       
    }]
}
```

I need to add the values of the field wage and show it in an handlebar template as total .. here want I need is sum up the values of wages in the array of objects with filtering some criteria I have tried many ways here are some

```
Person.aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            "name": req.body.name
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "total": {
                "$sum": "$details.wage"
            }
        }
    }
]).exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

my working code to show the values

```
Person.find({
        names: req.body.woker
    }) // <=> wrapper for Model.find() ...
    .then(documents => {
        // create context Object with 'usersDocuments' key
        const context = {
            usersDocuments: documents.map(documents => {
                return {
                    details: documents.details,
                }
            })
        }
        console.log(context.usersDocuments)

        // rendering usersDocuments from context Object
        res.render('employee/individuallist', {
            employeeName: req.body.woker,
            usersDocuments: context.usersDocuments,
        })
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).send(error))
})
```

my handlebar template code

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Work of (Seller Name)</th>
            <th>Number of sacks</th>
            <th>Kooli</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            
            {{#each usersDocuments}}
            {{#each this.details}}
                                                    
        <tr>
            <td>{{this.date}}</td>
            <td>{{this.sellername}}</td>
            <td>{{this.chack}}</td>
            <td>{{this.kooli}}</td>
        </tr>
                                                  
        {{/each}}

        {{/each}}
                    
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Total Amount</td>
            <td>{{this.total}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems because `details` is an array you can't just target each item's `wage` by `"$details.wage"` you would probably need to [unwind (see the example usage)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-aggregation) the array which will produce multiple entries that will have a `details` object where you can use `details.wage`

Maybe a simpler solution would be to use [reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce) to aggregate a total:

```js
Person.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
      "name": req.body.name
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "total": {
        "$reduce": {
           input: "$details",
           initialValue: 0,
           in: { 
             $add: ["$$value", "$$this.wage"]
           }
         }
      }
    }
  }
]).exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```